# Use different row heights in heatmap in R

Tags: r, heatmap

I have a data frame like this:

```
X<-c(100,90,80,70,65,60,55,50,45,40)    
Y<-c(10,20,30,40,35,30,25,20,15,10) 
Z<-c(50,40,30,20,30,40,50,60,70,80)
df<-as.data.frame(cbind(X,Y,Z))
df
     X  Y  Z
1  100 10 50
2   90 20 40
3   80 30 30
4   70 40 20
5   65 35 30
6   60 30 40
7   55 25 50
8   50 20 60
9   45 15 70
10  40 10 80
```

X,Y and Z represent distance or length of 0.23Km, 1.756Km and 3.452Km respectively. I am able to create a heatmap like this but all rows have the same height:

```
m<-as.matrix(df)
library(fields)
z<-colorRampPalette(c("green","yellow", "red","black"))
image(m, col=z(50), xaxt= "n", yaxt= "n")
```

I want to adjust the height of the heatmap cells according to the lengths of X, Y and Z the height of heat map rows will be proportional to the given lengths of X, Y and Z (0.23 unit, 1.756 units and 3.452 units).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
image(m[,c(1,1,1,2,2,3)], col=z(50), xaxt= "n", yaxt= "n")
```

[image]

Comment: You are kind of repeating the rows multiple times. Given the length of X, Y, and Z in the example is integer (1Km, 2Km and 3KM) your method works. But suppose the length of X, Y, Z is decimal, e.g., 0.23Km, 1.756Km and 3.452Km. Then how will you adjust the row heights of the heatmap? Thanks.

Comment: Then use the `rect` function. For example, `ht <- c(3/6, 2/6, 1/6);
plot.new(); for (i in seq_len(dim(m)[2]) ) for (j in seq_len(dim(m)[1]) ) rect(0.1*(j-1), 1.8*(i-1)*ht[i], 0.1*(j), 1.8*i*ht[i], col = cols[round(m[j, i])/2], border = NA)`

Comment: In my comment above, `ht <- c(3/6, 2/6, 1/6)` records the relative heights of each row.

Comment: In your case, you would set `ht <- c(0.23, 1.756, 3.452); ht <- ht / sum(ht);`

Comment: perhaps I could do this ` image(m[,c(rep(1:3, times=c(230,1756,3452)))], col=z(50), xaxt= "n", yaxt= "n")`

Comment: Yes, but using `rect` is more straightforward and will plot faster.